# Remote debugging from visual studio to raspberry

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi

I would like to deploy a local .net-core project and debug from vs code to my raspberry on raspbian.

I installed this extension: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh

I can connect succesfully via ssh to my raspberry but the problem is that I can no longer work on my actual local solution as the explorer is binded to my remote raspberry.

Is there a way to work on my local project and just deploy on the raspberry for debugging? Is it the right tool?

Thank you

Comment: That VSCode extension is for "remote development", meaning the code is compiled and debugged on the remote machine. If you just want .NET Core remote debugging, you need to follow posts such as https://www.hanselman.com/blog/RemoteDebuggingWithVSCodeOnWindowsToARaspberryPiUsingNETCoreOnARM.aspx

Comment: this part made me think it was possible : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_debugging-on-the-ssh-host

Comment: For remote debugging, you only have a debugger on the remote machine (in Scott's post, vsdbg). The source code is on your local machine and you use your local VSCode for development. For remote development, however, you actually run the whole VSCode stuffs and the source code on the remote machine, which talks back to the VSCode instance on your local machine. That's the major difference (and why your local code is not used in remote development), and debugging should work in both cases if you configure them properly.